# function to find max number in list

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function which finds the max number in a list (without using the max() command)

however my function doesn't work for negative numbers I don't think? how do I fix this? thanks! for example in my second print test it prints  0 instead of -3.

```
def my_max(data):
    """finds max number in list"""
    maximum = 0 
    for num in data:
        if num > maximum:
            maximum = num
    return maximum 
print(my_max([11, 99, 3, -6]))
print(my_max([-3, -5, -9, -10]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions to that:

- Putting a ridiculously big negative number as initial maximum like `-10000000` (won't work in any case and is ugly) or `-math.inf` (will work in any case but is still ugly)
- Putting the first item of your list as initial maximum (`data[0]`) (will work in any case).

  Explanation for this 2nd solution : If the first item of your list is the biggest one, the condition will always resolve to `False` and this inital maximum will be returned, or, it'll replace it by an other bigger item in the list and finally return the biggest.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are initializing you maximum variable with an arbitrary value (zero) that is already larger than -3.    Try initializing it with the first element in the list maximum = data[0]

Answer (score 0):

One of the more obscure number types in Python is `math.inf` -- infinity. This can be produced by:

`from math import inf`, and then using `inf` or `-inf` (negative infinity),

**or**

`float("inf")` for positive infinity, and `float ("-inf")` for negative infinity